# Gmail API with Golang

Tags: go, gmail-api

I want to create an API that sends emails from my email account to another email account using the gmail api. However, there is not much documentation for this on google's website, mostly in java and python. I was wondering if anyone was able to figure this out. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: There is  a Go specific page for creating a client at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go.  From there, you will need to read the guides for other languages and the Go API reference documentation to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet code for creating a draft email:

```
var draft gmail.Draft
var m = gomail.NewMessage()
m.SetHeader("From", "your email")
m.SetHeader("To", "other email")
m.SetHeader("Subject", "test")
m.SetBody("text/plain", "Hello")

// if you want to attach files to the draft email
for _, attachment := range Attachments {
    m.Attach(attachment)
}
buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
if _, err = m.WriteTo(buffer); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
var msg gmail.Message
msg.Raw = base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(buffer.Bytes())
draft.Message = &msg
result, err := srv.Users.Drafts.Create(caller.Email, &draft).Do()
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("create draft failed: %s", err.Error())
}
```